# CSV data not being inserted into corresponding MySQL table

Tags: mysql, csv, mysqlimport

I have a CSV file that follows this pattern:

```
cust_id,cust_name,cust_add_1,cust_add_2,cust_city,cust_state,cust_zip,cust_email
100024,BALE #DIANA & ROY,2944 SOME RD, ,AKRON,OH,44556,an@other.net
100139,SMITH #JOHN & LINDA,1569 ANOTHER WAY, ,SARASOTA,FL,65478,
100263,DOLE #BOB,5947 LONG RD, ,GRANITE FALLS,NC,12345,
.
.
. continued
```

This file represents thousands and thousands of rows of data, and I am trying to insert all of it into a MySQL table. I created the corresponding table with the following statement:

```
CREATE TABLE customer (
    cust_id INT(7) NOT NULL,
    cust_name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    cust_add_1 VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    cust_add_2 VARCHAR(50),
    cust_city VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    cust_state CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    cust_zip INT(5) NOT NULL,
    cust_email VARCHAR(60),
    PRIMARY KEY (cust_id)
);
```

Then I tried the following on the command line:

```
msyqlimport -u root --local csv_import ~/path/to/customer.csv
```

When I tried `SELECT * FROM customer` after running mysqlimport, I was given the following result-set:

```
+---------+-----------+------------+------------+-----------+------------+----------+------------+
| cust_id | cust_name | cust_add_1 | cust_add_2 | cust_city | cust_state | cust_zip | cust_email |
+---------+-----------+------------+------------+-----------+------------+----------+------------+
|       0 |           |            | NULL       |           |            |          | NULL       |
+---------+-----------+------------+------------+-----------+------------+----------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I'm not very experienced in the area of importing CSV data into MySQL, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

As per ThisSuitIsBlackNot's answer, I tried the following command (BTW the `--local` option is needed):

```
mysqlimport -u root --local --fields-terminated-by=',' --fields-optionally-enclosed-by='"' --lines-terminated-by='\n' csv_import ~/path/to/customer.csv
```

This produced slightly better results but wasn't what I need, so I tried it like this:

```
mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '~/path/to/customer.csv'
    -> INTO TABLE customer
    -> FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    -> OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
    -> LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

After both of these, `SELECT * FROM customer` produced this result-set:

```
+---------+-----------+------------+------------+-----------+------------+----------+-------------------+
| cust_id | cust_name | cust_add_1 | cust_add_2 | cust_city | cust_state | cust_zip | cust_email        |
+---------+-----------+------------+------------+-----------+------------+----------+-------------------+
100024 |0 | cust_name | cust_add_1 | cust_add_2 | cust_city | cu         | cust_    | cust_email
+---------+-----------+------------+------------+-----------+------------+----------+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

This is obviously not what I need, but it's getting closer.

Comment: *Sigh*, please never post real data on the internets. If you're going to make something up then do so, minimal obfuscation **does NOT work**. For instance, the last record you have there you have one too many asterisk's in the surname.

Comment: Trust me, the only way the data I posted resembles the original data is in form.

Comment: Are you sure your CSV uses `\n` as the EOL character? You can double check this in a text editor like notepad++ or vim.

Comment: The data in customer.csv seems to use `\n` as the EOL character. For instance, in both vim and gedit, the line number in the bottom right increments correctly. However, when running `head customer.csv` it still loads the entire file. I have another file (vendor.csv, which is identical in form) that is to go into this database as well, and it is functioning perfectly; `head vendor.csv` is loading only the first few lines, and the same `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` statement is inserting the data into the vendor table nicely.

Comment: Try `od -c /path/to/file` and see if the lines in customer.csv end with `\r \n`. I suspect your file is using Windows line endings.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't actually mean to post that comment. Anyways, I got it sorted out. Turns out customer.csv uses `\r` as its EOL character, while all the others use `\n`. You helped me out a bunch.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. I'll update my answer to include info about line endings in case someone in the future has the same issue.

Comment: Although I do find it odd that the line ending would be only `\r`, which was the EOL on *old* Macs (pre-OS X, i.e. more than a decade old). If anything, I would have expected `\r\n`, which is the Windows EOL, unless the CSV was generated on really old hardware.

Comment: I just found out that it was generated on an AS/400.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Field separators

The default field separator for `mysqlimport` is a tab character. You need to tell `mysqlimport` to split fields on commas instead:

```sh
mysqlimport --fields-terminated-by=',' ...
```

This isn't quite enough, though, because if your CSV follows the spec, fields containing commas will be surrounded by double quotes. You need to tell `mysqlimport` that it shouldn't treat commas inside quotes as field separators:

```sh
mysqlimport --fields-terminated-by=',' --fields-optionally-enclosed-by='"' ...
```

In some CSVs, *all* fields are double quoted, whether they contain commas or not. This is not the case with your data, but for future reference, `mysqlimport` also provides the option

```sh
--fields-enclosed-by=string
```

I'm not sure, but I assume performance would be better on a CSV where all fields are quoted if you use `--fields-enclosed-by='"'` instead of `--fields-optionally-enclosed-by='"'`.

### Line separators

The default line separator for `mysqlimport` is a newline `\n`. This should work for files generated on UNIX/Linux/Mac OS X, but if the EOL sequence in your file is something different (for example, `\r\n` in most files created on Windows), you need to specify that as well:

```sh
mysqlimport --lines-terminated-by='\r\n'
```

Apparently, Wordpad uses '\r' as a line ending, as did Macs prior to Mac OS X.

### Skipping column headers

Generally you don't want to import the names of your columns into your table, since the table already has its own column names. You can skip the first X number of lines in your file like this:

```sh
mysqlimport --ignore-lines=X
```

### Putting it all together

To import a CSV file where

- fields that contain commas are double quoted
- fields that don't contain commas are not quoted
- lines end in `\r\n`
- the first line contains column names, which you want to ignore

you would run

```sh
mysqlimport --fields-terminated-by=',' \
            --fields-optionally-enclosed-by='"' \
            --lines-terminated-by='\r\n' \
            --ignore-lines=1 \
            db_name table_name.csv
```

Note that `mysqlimport` determines the table to import into by simply stripping off the file extension, so the above example will try to import the data from `table_name.csv` into the `table_name` table. Also, if you're running this on the server, you *shouldn't* need the `--local` option, although the wording in the documentation is a little obtuse.

You can also use the equivalent SQL statement

```sql
LOAD DATA INFILE 'table_name.csv' INTO TABLE table_name
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
  IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

(`mysqlimport` is just a command-line interface to `LOAD DATA INFILE`)

See the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html) for `LOAD DATA INFILE` for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helped me get better results, but it's still not quite there. Please see my updated question.